# Migrate / Copy Huge data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, migration, data-transfer, database-administration

I have huge tables in oracle database, appx 1 crore+ (10 million+) rows and want to migrate / copy those table and data in sql server.

Currently I am using Import functionality of SQL Server for this process. But it takes a day for this process and takes too much time.

Is there any better way? Any good outcome or step (SSIS, Any other functional step) to follow for this process?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Any way to move question?